# How would somebody who controls magnetic fields prevent being pulled towards the source of a magnetic material

Tags: science-based, magic, electromagnetism

As I have mentioned before I have a hero who controls magnetism. They control magnetism via a magnetic organ that can generate multi tesla fields. However I do not want this organ to be pulled out of body upon the use of the magnetic ability.

So how could this hero prevent the magnetic organ from escaping the body with minimal hand-waving. Also I have read this question, “ [https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148561/how-can-powerful-telekinesis-avoid-violating-newtons-3rd-law”](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148561/how-can-powerful-telekinesis-avoid-violating-newtons-3rd-law%E2%80%9D)

However it assumes that the telekinesis applies to the whole body which my magnetism does not have.

Comment: Running spikes on his shoes?

Comment: What would that do by the way

Comment: Assuming the source of magnetic material is in a reasonably horizontal direction and that the spikes are long enough and strong enough .. do you really need any more hints? ;) dig in and lean back.

Comment: How does the organ generates magnetic field? I rubbed my hand and I can lift a balloon without having my skin peeling off so we need to learn more about the source of magnetism?

Comment: It generates the magnetic field via a solenoid that has an electric current pumped into it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy Marvel's Magneto, the organ should be capable of generating such fields outside the body of the hero - that, or the hero can shape the fields however they want.

If you want a very simple explanation, the hero manipulates two different force fields. One is the electromagnetic field, and the other is a field that acts only on the organ. This extra field enacts a different force on the organ that exacyly counters whatever pull it feels from the magnetic force (after coming up with this I'm gonna send my resumé to Disney).

Answer (score 0):

You could handwave that the Required Secondary Power here is that the organ naturally "roots" itself in the magnetic field of the Earth, so it cannot be moved except by extreme force. This would also allow for some interesting story plotlines such as the powers not working correctly in space or the hero discovering he can become an immovable object (except without the ability to tolerate extreme pressures on his body).